# Detect ajax vs regular browser post in Python Pylons

Tags: python, post, pylons

How can I detect whether a form was submitted via an AJAX post or just a browser submit in Pylons?

For example:

```
if 'name' in request.POST:
    #Do something
```

Would be true if 'name' was submitted via ajax or just a regular post.  How can I differentiate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `request.is_xhr`.
This relies on your javascript framework to set the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header, but that's not bad since most frameworks like jquery add this header.

Answer (score 1):

I check for the accepts json in the request headers

```
def controller_accepts_json():
    return 'application/json' in request.headers.get('accept', '')
```

Comment: Sorry, too early in the morning. Of course this only works if you're making json requests and not an xml/html/text ajax request.

Comment: Additionally I'd never rely on clients sending proper accept-* headers.

Answer (score 0):

this may help.

```
import os

os.environ.has_key('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH')
```